# Ansible - Synchronize module asks for password - No solution yet?

Tags: ansible

As per my search on google i see that many are facing this issue where the synchronize module asks to enter the password even though the password less login is setup between the control and target machines using the sshkeygen.

All other modules being used in the yml works fine without prompting for the password except for synchronize  module.

I see the [ticket](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2156) raised for this in ansible forum is closed but I did not get what the solution is.

Just want to know if there really was a solution or this is still pending from ansible?

Below is the task that poses the concern explained above

```
- hosts: testservers
  tasks:
  - name: sync a directory(can be a jboss as well)
    synchronize:
        src: /home/admin/VPNSimulator/
        dest: /home/admin/vasanth/
        rsync_opts:
           - "--exclude-from=rsync.excludes_1"
           - "--delete-before"
```

Below is the thread where one person (makmanalp) at the last says issue is fixed in version 2.0.1.0, the version of ansible I am using is 2.6.2 so I believe this fix should have been present in my version as well. But fails to work.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Ansible version `2.7.2` on CentOS 7.

Comment: Can you post a more verbose output (using `-vvv`) so we can see the authentication process? I use `synchronize` very often and never ran into that problem.